# Fetch all columns from multiple tables and order them based on the date each of rows saved in tables

Tags: php, html

I am designing an advertising website and I have many ads from different cases like cars, real estate and electrical devices. Thus I have 3 different tables with different column numbers in my database, one for each of them. These tables do not have any common column name except id and date, if it is a problem, I can change them too. Now the problem is that I want to show all of ads in my first page of website and order them by date. I have writen this code. But it is really difficult because every table has more than 60 columns. Is there not any way to make it easier like `select*from`?

```html
$resultset= $mysqli->query("SELECT realestate.rentprice, 
       cars.carprice,electrical.harddisk
    FROM realestate,cars,electrical");
    echo $resultset->num_rows;
?>
```

To simplify the code,  I have removed unnecessary lines.

Comment: when you say not working, what you mean? Not working that you getting error or not getting any result back?
Also could you please run SELECT * FROM realestate;
                    SELECT * FROM cars ;
                    SELECT * FROM electrical; separately and show us there results please? They need to have equal number of columns for union to work.

Comment: thank you vary much for your answering. i did not know  They need to have equal number of columns for union to work. as i said these tables do not have equal number of columns.

Comment: That's fine what you can do in your select query select few colums that you desire and make sure number match if in some table you don't have enough column use select 1 as dummyColumn to increase number of columns if that makes sense.

Comment: i edit my code like you said.but it is really difficult because every table has more than 60 columns.  Is not there any way to make it easer like select*from

Comment: and do you need to fetch all columns?

Comment: yes. i need to fetch all of the columns. and as i said i have a date column in each of the tables and i want to order fetched rows based on date order

Comment: ok from your requirements you have two options: 1. Don't use union make 3 calls to db and do sorting by date in php world not in db world. 2. Make temp table insert data in it from all three tables and use mysql to sort by date. Depending on your skill and comfort level you can pick one but those are your choices.

Comment: which of them take shorter time to process as i said i have many ads and i do not what to processing  takes long time.

Comment: For scalability reasons I would prefer doing it in mysql world so first option. Since 2nd option can lead to ran out of memory issue.

Comment: and what do you mean sorting by date in php world not in db world. how can i do that could please make an example code

Comment: Sorry my bad not 1st option you need 2nd option push data to a temp table and then sort by date using mysql.

Comment: ok. how can i  create a temp table with multiple tables which have different columns. can you make a simple code ?

Comment: do those tables have anything common like some sort of id which can be use to join those table? Or can you please show table structures so that I can come up with something for you?

Comment: yes all of them have "id" and "date"  and "image name" columns

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116288/discussion-between-perdeep-singh-and-user6362236).

Comment: Improved language and fromatting